# Windows 2003 Server Suddenly Drops Connections to everything but PING and port 80 (webserver)

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

I'm running a Windows 2003 Dedicated server, and the box has been rock solid for more than 2 years now. Just recently, I have had an issue where after a certain ammount of time the server will just stop accepting connections on all ports except 80, and still responds to pings. If you surf to a static HTML page on the box, you can display it. If you pull up a PHP file that has an outside database connection, it fails. RDP refuses to connect, and LogMeIn reports that "The connection was reset"

The only fix at this time is to have the provider physically reboot my box to correct the issue. The event log doesn't seem to be leaving helpful messages, and I am at a lost to what is causing this error since I have not installed any new software in months on it.

Any tips or help would be appreciated to tracking down this issue. I don't mind updating the question as responses come in, I just do not know where to start troubleshooting because it seems random at this time.

Update:

Restarting WAMP does not correct the issue, nothing seems to be hogging memory at the time of the issue, and I am able to RDP into the box, to at least restart it (had it disabled). But connections out to MySQL databases, and FTP connections in or out fail. Connections over LogMeIn continue to fail. Is there anything I can use to trace this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there's some outbound firewall filtering going on.  You could install and run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and see where your packets are going.

Comment: I'll give Wireshark a try, didn't even think about it. Hopefully I can get some pointers from there.

Comment: It seems I *may* nailed the issue down to a botched Windows Update. Wireshark gave a pointer to it, so I'm marking this as correct now.